# Aplicativo no Eclipse para Iphone

Tags: java, android, ios, objective-c, eclipse

Estou precisando de uma ajuda, e nem sei o que fazer. Criei um aplicativo bem simples no *Eclipse Kepler*, coloquei na Google Play e ficou ótimo.

Gostaria de saber se é possível e qual a melhor maneira de "*converter*" o meu projeto de *Android* para *IOS*. Como tem muitos usuários solicitando o mesmo aplicativo para o *iPhone*, quero desenvolver o aplicativo para o mesmo, porem eu não sei nada de *Objective-C* e nem tenho Mac nem nada. Por isso quero saber se há possibilidade de "converter" meu aplicativo já existente?

Obs: Criei o *app* a base de tutoriais.

Comment: Acredito que uma reformulada na questão, esclarecimento e explicando melhor a dúvida, pode ser que a mesma possa ser reconsiderada.

Comment: Na verdade eu tenho minhas dúvidas se ela deveria ter sido mesmo fechada. De qualquer forma, votei para reabrir.

Comment: "Converter" de forma automática acredito que não seja possível (até onde conheço), existe sim alguns ferramentas que prometem criar aplicativos "híbridos" para Android e IOS, mas muitos deles tem sua própria linguagem de Programação (utilizando uma linguagem intermediaria), posso citar alguns exemplos como [PhoneGap](http://phonegap.com/) (que utiliza html, css e javascript, e resulta em aplicativos baseados em web, executados em WebView), e [Xamarim](http://xamarin.com/)(que utiliza C# e "segundo o site deles" resulta em um aplicativo nativo hibrido). Obs: nunca utilizei Xamarim.

Comment: Vou utilizar o PhoneGap aqui e tentar recriar o app. Muito obrigado pela atenção, e se tiver algum tutorial sobre PhoneGap me passe o link por favor.

Answer (score 1):

Converter assim automaticamente infelizmente não tem como. Mas tem alguns meios, um deles são os aplicativos híbridos com HTML, Javascript e CSS (que é o que eu conheço um pouco mais). Tem outras opções também como citado nos comentários.

Alguns programadores dizem que utilizando destes meios o aplicativo acaba perdendo um pouco o desempenho, e depende de conexão para funcionar. Porém eu não posso lhe confirmar essa informação pois eu ainda não utilizei este meio, pretendo utilizar logo, mesmo que seja apenas de forma experimental.

Espero ter ajudado.